Bottle gourd only generating male flowers
I have a bottle gourd plant that is about 6 plus feet in lenght. Plenty of male flowers but no female flowers. Soil is not crusty and not too wet. I added some home made compost and chiken manure (pellets) about 2-3 weeks ago and do not see any female flowers. Any tips?

Many squash-family plants make only male flowers at the start of flower production, and wait to start making female flowers for some time.
A considerably smaller number have plants that produce only one or the other throughout their life.
If you only have one plant, hope for the former case. There isn't much else you can do at this point (or perhaps there is? See added paragrapgh below.) If you have a specific known variety of bottle gourd you might be able to research whether that one is prone to the latter case.
This site (no affiliation, just found while looking for more info) claims that the main vine on gourds produces only male flowers, and that pruning the tip will encourage it to grow laterals with female flowers.

Thanks for the recommendation. Controlling the growth helped.
